# EXT4 Journaling - Problem

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, ext4, journaling

Basically my root (`/`) ext4 partition keeps being mounted as read-only when I apply internal journaling feature. I understand that this should be default, but today I had been trying to apply external journals to ramdisk for each of my ext4 partitions since I am using an SSD and wanted to obtain maximum performance from it (which journaling impedes: http://raid6.com.au/posts/fs_ext4_external_journal/). I'd gotten myself into a mess when after applying external journals to ramdisk, I rebooted my machine to find that it would no longer boot since the ramdisk's were not persistent and the ext4 partitions were trying to load/apply external journals at ramdisks that no longer existed so I then had to "rescue" the installation with the CentOS 7 Live CD "rescue" feature.

So basically, I can no longer apply the internal journal on my root partition. I have corrected it on my other partitions (which strangely enough only `/opt` will unmount without being "busy"). IS there a way to fix this? I'd like to have internal journaling on while I properly get round implementing journaling to external ramdisk.

I am trying to turn back on the internal journaling feature of the ext4 partition with:

`tune2fs -O has_journal /dev/sda3`

But when rebooting, the root partition mounts as read-only, and I cannot unmount it and remount as `rw`. So I have to turn it off with:

`tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sda3`

All feedback welcome.

Comment: If you're trying to put your journal on a ramdisk, you'd be better off running without a journal at all.  A journal's whole purpose is to help the filesystem recover cleanly if it gets interrupted by a power outage or system crash.  This won't work if the journal is on a ramdisk.

Comment: I see. So pointless exercise then. But still, the question remains, how would I fix the read only problem that I am experiencing when re-applying the internal journal?

Comment: Is there anything in your logs that explains *why* the root filesystem is being mounted read-only when you enable the journal?

Comment: I already checked that from `dmesg` and checked `/var/log/messages`. Nothing obvious.

Comment: From [fs_ext4_external_journal_caveats](http://raid6.com.au/posts/fs_ext4_external_journal_caveats/) When the journal device is lost:

1) Remove invalid journal:

`tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/ext4-device`

and run `fsck` to check/repair file system.

2) Internal journal can be created with the following command: `tune2fs -O has_journal /dev/ext4-device`